# Import functions from local file only when duplicates exist in super folder

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to use functions from a local file. I had conflicts when I just use

```
import myfunc3 as my
```

I had the same file name in the super directory, so I am using the following

```
from . import myfunc3 as my
```

This results in an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'myfunc3' from '__main__'
```

myfunc3.py had "if **name** == '**main**':" and removing this line doesn't change the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parent directory of `myfunc3` to `sys.path` and then use `import myfunc3 as my`.

`from . import myfun3 as my` works because you're explicitly saying "import from the parent directory of the current module" whereas `import myfunc3 as my` implicitly imports from available PATHs", i.e. `sys.path`.